# Iterate through nested objects Array to get ID and Name

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

```
components: any = [
    {
      id: "17:12610",
      name: "custom-component",
      hasWarning: true,
      selectableKey: 'id',
      preview: 'thumbnailLink',
      children: {
        "17:12610": {
          "name": "cc-1",
          "type": "instance",
          "children": {
            "7:43": {
              "name": "icon-slot",
              "children": {},
              "type": "div"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ];

Object.keys(this.components[0].children).forEach((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
```

I am iterating like this but its only giving me the first ID.
I want to get each children ID & Name. Also I want to track the index so that I can make changes on particular index

**I want the output like this:**

- **id**: 17:12610
  **name**: cc-1
- **id**: 7:43
  **name**: icon-slot

Comment: the 'children' object only has 1 entry in it. What other entries are you looking to access?

Comment: In children there are further objects with respective IDs. I want id and names like this: id: 17:12610 name: cc-1. And next id: 7:23 name:icon-slot

Answer (score 1):

```
let child = components[0].children;
while (child) {
  const id = Object.keys(child)[0];
  const name = child[id].name;
  console.log('id: ' + id + ' name: ' + name);
  child = child[id].children;
}
```

Comment: do not provide code only answers with no details it will not be easy for the user to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying `components[0]` before your forEach function. If you have multiple elements in your components array then you will need something like:

```
(this.components).forEach((root => {
      (root.children).forEach((child) => {
          console.log('id:' + child + ' name:' + child.name);
    }
  }
);
```

Also, looking at your array construction, you have created an array of objects, not an array of key value pairs and so they will not have a key associated with them.  If you want keys associated with them, change your object {} to a nested array [].

You edited your question to add the desired output format. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: its also displaying the same result, only first ID

Comment: See my edited answer. If that doesn't work, enclose child in console.log() function to Object.keys(child) but leave child.name alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function to achieve the solution. Something like this:

```js
const component = [{"id":"17:12610","name":"custom-component","hasWarning":true,"selectableKey":"id","preview":"thumbnailLink","children":{"17:12610":{"name":"cc-1","type":"instance","children":{"7:43":{"name":"icon-slot","children":{},"type":"div"}}}}}];

const recursive = (arr, formedArr=[]) => arr.reduce((a,e)=>{
    Object.entries(e.children || e).forEach(([id, {name, children}])=>{
      a.push({id, name});
      if(children) recursive([children], a);
    });
    return a;
},formedArr);

console.log(recursive(component));
```